# Django time data '2024-02-15' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d '

Tags: python, django

I'm having problems to strip a date:

```
pFecha = datetime.strptime(pFechaDesde, '%Y/%m/%d')
```

Where:

pFechaDesde =  '2024-02-15'

The date was got from a input type date

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error indicates, it uses hyphens, so:

```
pFecha = datetime.strptime(pFechaDesde, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

---

> **Note**: It is better to use a [**`Form`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/)
> than to perform manual validation and cleaning of the data. A `Form` will not
> only simplify *rendering* a form in HTML, but it also makes it more convenient
> to *validate* the input, and *clean* the data to a more convenient type.